# How can I display my response messages that I send in node js on my frontend with Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am trying to build a basic login/signup app with the mern stack.I am new to it. While making the backend with node and express I have added lot of json messages in the code like-

`return res.status(400).json({message:"Unable to find user by this id"})`
`return res.status(404).json({message:"User doesnt exist"});`

How can I display this json data to my frontend with react?

This is the handleSubmit code-

```
const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(inputs);
    if(isSignup){
      sendRequest("signup")
      .then((data)=>localStorage.setItem("userId",data.user._id))
      .then(()=>dispath(authActions.login())) 
      .then(()=>navigate("/blogs"))
    }else{
      sendRequest()
      .then((data)=>localStorage.setItem("userId",data.user._id))
      .then(()=>dispath(authActions.login()))
      .then(()=>navigate("/blogs"))
      .then(data=>console.log(data))
      
    }
  }
```

This is the return div code-

```
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Box display="flex" flexDirection={'column'} 
      alignItems='center' 
      maxWidth={400}
      justifyContent={'center'} 
      boxShadow="10px 10px 20px #ccc"
      padding={3}
      margin="auto"
      marginTop={5}
      borderRaidus={5}>
        <Typography variant="h2" padding={3} textAlign="center">{isSignup?"Signup":"Login"}</Typography>
        {isSignup && <TextField name="name" onChange={handleChange} value={inputs.name} placeholder='name' margin="normal"/>}
        <TextField name="email" onChange={handleChange} value={inputs.email} type={'email'} placeholder='email' margin='normal'/>
        <TextField name="password" onChange={handleChange} value={inputs.password} type={'password'} placeholder='password' margin='normal'/>
        <Button type={"submit"} variant="contained" sx={{borderRadius:3,marginTop:3}} color="warning">Submit</Button>
        <Button onClick={()=>setIsSignup(!isSignup)} sx={{borderRadius:3,marginTop:3}}>
          Change to {isSignup ?"Login":"Signup"}</Button>
      </Box>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Auth
```

Comment: Can you show the `handleSubmit` code?

Comment: I have added the handelSubmit code

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one.

```
const handleSubmit = async(...) => {
 ...
 try{
  const response = await axios.post(...);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
 }catch(){
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. I have added the handleSubmit code in the question could you check that?